# Will the Graph API support getting a video's "length" property?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

The Graph API does not appear to support the length property. I'm able to get a video's length with the FQL API, but I'd rather use the Graph API since FQL is being deprecated.

It seems odd that a video's length property would not be an optional field given that videos displayed on Facebook pages have their lengths prominently displayed by default.

Will there be future support for the "length" field on videos? I'd like to see support for this before FQL is gone.